# SAPUI5 formatter function returns its parameter

Tags: sapui5, formatter

I have a very strange issue with formatter function.

I have the following formatter:

```js
_formatter: function(sAccessLevel){
    switch(sAccessLevel){
        case "fullAccess":
            return true;
        case "readOnly":
            return false;
        case "norefund":
            return false;
        case "nodiscount":
            return false;
        default:
            return false;
    }
},
```

for the following field:

```js
<Column visible="{path: 'modelName>/Access', formatter: '_formatter'}" >
    <header hAlign="Middle" vAlign="Middle">
        <Text text="{i18n>discount}" textAlign="Center"/>
    </header>
</Column>
```

And in try-catch block I sometimes get the following error:

`Error: "nodiscount" is of type string, expected boolean for property "visible" of Element sap.m.Column#__column154`

or

`Error: "fullAccess" is of type string, expected boolean for property "visible" of Element sap.m.Column#__column489`

When I try to reproduce the error, the code works fine, but in production system's log I see the above error.

How this error possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Inside the formatter try `return  (sAccessLevel && sAccessLevel === "fullAccess" ) ? true : false;`

Answer (score 2):

Its a simple mistake. While giving the **formatter** in **XML view** we have to give the **.formatterFunctionName** as below.

```
<Column visible="{path: 'modelName>/Access', formatter: '._formatter'}" >
    <header hAlign="Middle" vAlign="Middle">
        <Text text="{i18n>discount}" textAlign="Center"/>
    </header>
</Column>
```

In the controller implement your formatter function as usual.